# Approximating KL divergence between mixture of gaussian and standard normal

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, conditional-probability, variational-analysis

I am reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02157.pdf), and I don't get the proposition given in the appendix of this paper.

> **Proposition 1**
>
> Let $K,L \in \mathbb{N}$, a propbability vector $(p_1,...,p_L)$, and $\Sigma_i\in\mathbb{R}^{K\times K}$ positive definite for $i=1,...,L$ with the elements of each $\Sigma_i$ not dependent on $K$.
>
> Let $q(x):= \sum_{i=1}^L p_i \mathscr{N}(x| \mu_i, \Sigma_i)$ be a mixture of Gaussians with $L$ components and $\mu_i\in\mathbb{R}^K$ normally distributed, and let $p(x) \sim \mathscr{N}(0,I_K)$.
>
> The KL divergence between $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ can be approximated as:
>
> $KL(q(x)||p(x)) \approx \sum_{i=1}^L \frac{p_i}{2}(\mu_i^T \mu_i + tr(\Sigma_i) - K(1+\log 2\pi) - \log|\Sigma_i|)$.

What does it mean that $\mu_i$ is normally distributed here? The conclusion of this proposition is approximating the KL divergence for **given $\mu_i$'s** as you can see here. There is no randomness!..

Moreover, the author asserts the following:

> Note that we can write $H(q(x))$ as $-\sum_{i=1}^L p_i \int \mathscr{N}(\epsilon_i|0,I_K) \log q(\mu_i + L_i\epsilon_i) d\epsilon_i$ with $L_iL_i^T = \Sigma_i$.
>
> Also, $q(\mu_i + L_i\epsilon_i) = \sum_{j=1}^L p_j (2\pi)^{-K/2}|\Sigma_j|^{-1/2} exp(-\frac{1}{2} ||\mu_j - \mu_i - L_i\epsilon_i ||^2_{\Sigma_j}$
>
> **Since $\mu_i$'s are assumed to be normally distributed, the quantity $\mu_j - \mu_i - L_i\epsilon_i$ is also normally distributed. Using the expectation of the generalised $\chi^2$ distribution with $K$ degrees of freedom, we have that for $K>>0$ there exists that $||\mu_j - \mu_i - L_i\epsilon_i||^2_{\Sigma_j} >>0$ for $i\neq j$**
>
> Thus, we can approximate $q(\mu_i + L_i\epsilon_i) \approx p_i (2\pi)^{-K/2} |\Sigma_i|^{-1/2} exp(-\frac{1}{2} \epsilon_i^T \epsilon_i)$

I completely do not get what the bolded line is talking about and how that makes sense..

Could somebody please explain why it makes sense?

Comment: $\mu_i$s can be random variables with some particular distributions. But then, the $q(x)$ will also be a random variable with some particular distribution. The KL  divergence calculation should therefore be given not between densities but between the random variables having some densities.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I do not get your last sentence. How exactly the KL will be defined then? Could you please write that as a concrete equation?

Comment: $KL(X,Y)=KL(p_X|p_Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are their density functions.